# remove all quotation marks from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, removeall, quotation-marks

I have a data frame `rep` that looks like this:

```
> head(rep)
     position chrom  value label  
[1,] "17408"  "chr1" "0"   "miRNA"
[2,] "17409"  "chr1" "0"   "miRNA"
[3,] "17410"  "chr1" "0"   "miRNA"
[4,] "17411"  "chr1" "0"   "miRNA"
[5,] "17412"  "chr1" "0"   "miRNA"
[6,] "17413"  "chr1" "0"   "miRNA"
```

How can I remove the quotation marks from all elements?

Note: `rep$position` and `rep$value` should be `numeric` type, `rep$chrom` and `rep$label` should be `character` type.

Comment: -1 for claiming to have a data.frame when it's obviously a matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As indicated by @Roland, you have a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`, and these have different default `print` methods. Sticking with a `matrix`, you can set `quote = FALSE` explicitly in `print` or you can use `noquote`.

Here is a basic example:

```
## Sample data
x <- matrix(c(17, "chr1", 0, "miRNA", 18, "chr1", 0, "miRNA"), nrow = 2, 
            byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(
              NULL, c("position", "chrom", "value", "label")))

## Default printing
x
#      position chrom  value label  
# [1,] "17"     "chr1" "0"   "miRNA"
# [2,] "18"     "chr1" "0"   "miRNA"

## Two options to make the quotes disappear
print(x, quote = FALSE)
#      position chrom value label
# [1,] 17       chr1  0     miRNA
# [2,] 18       chr1  0     miRNA
noquote(x)
#      position chrom value label
# [1,] 17       chr1  0     miRNA
# [2,] 18       chr1  0     miRNA
```

---

Also, as you figured out on your own, converting your `matrix` to a `data.frame` makes the quotes disappear. A `data.frame` is a more appropriate structure to hold your data if each column is a different type of data (numeric, character, factor, and so on). However, converting a `matrix` to a `data.frame` does not take care of the conversion of columns for you automatically. Instead, you can make use of `type.convert` (which is also used when creating a `data.frame` using `read.table` and family):

```
y <- data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(y)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ position: chr  "17" "18"
#  $ chrom   : chr  "chr1" "chr1"
#  $ value   : chr  "0" "0"
#  $ label   : chr  "miRNA" "miRNA"
y[] <- lapply(y, type.convert)
str(y)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ position: int  17 18
#  $ chrom   : Factor w/ 1 level "chr1": 1 1
#  $ value   : int  0 0
#  $ label   : Factor w/ 1 level "miRNA": 1 1
y
#   position chrom value label
# 1       17  chr1     0 miRNA
# 2       18  chr1     0 miRNA
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I wasn't sure whether `rep <- data.frame(rep)` alone would be sufficient. I wish I could give you more reputation points.

Comment: @biohazard, depends on the data! `data.frame(rep)` (as is) will create factors for each of your columns, which may or may not be what you want. I gave the `type.convert` option in case you wanted to replicate the `read.table` experience.

Answer (score 10):

Two steps: 1) get rid of quotation marks, 2) convert columns accordingly:

**The data**

```
x <- read.table(text='
position chrom  value label  
"\\"17408\\""  "\\"chr1\\"" "\\"0\\""   "\\"miRNA\\""
"\\"17409\\""  "\\"chr1\\"" "\\"0\\""   "\\"miRNA\\""'
, header=T)
```

**1) get rid of quotation marks**

```
library(stringr)
library(plyr)

del <- colwise(function(x) str_replace_all(x, '\"', ""))
x <- del(x)
```

**2) convert columns accordingly**

```
num <- colwise(as.numeric)    
x[c(1,3)] <- num(x[c(1,3)])
x

  position chrom value label
1    17408  chr1     0 miRNA
2    17409  chr1     0 miRNA
```

Comment: doesn't this only work for data frames?

Comment: @merik: Maybe yes, have not tried. Did probably not notice that the OP uses a matrix as he wrote data frame in his post.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer. What I have is not a data.frame but a matrix. Converting it to a data.frame got rid of the quotation marks. I am still wondering why though....

```
rep <- data.frame(rep)
> head(rep)
  position chrom value label
1    17408  chr1     0 miRNA
2    17409  chr1     0 miRNA
3    17410  chr1     0 miRNA
4    17411  chr1     0 miRNA
5    17412  chr1     0 miRNA
6    17413  chr1     0 miRNA
```

Comment: `print` methods are different for data.frames and matrices, that's why.